# Colored output in adb, e.g. for ls command

Tags: adb, shell, color

Is it possible to have colored output in `adb shell`, e.g. for the `ls` command?

I've tried `ls --color=auto .` etc, but that doesn't seem to work.

Colored output, however, works in `adb shell`, e.g. with

```
echo -e '\033[01;35m test \033[m'
```

Or does the ls command in `adb` not provide a "full feature" `ls` and it depends on the command?

---

Required Information:

- Device: HTC Desire S S510e
- Android: Gingerbread 2.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Screenshot with colored LS output]

As you can see from the screenshot, you can definitely get colored output in ls on android.
(side note - I've got some bashrc magic running so the default ls output is ls --color=auto)
Probably you're either running ls in a sh shell and not bash, you've got a watered-down OEM version of ls, or there's some strange magic happening between ADB on Windows and the linux terminal.

What device/android version/ROM are you running? What output does ls --version give?

Comment: `ls --version` does give me `--version: No such file or directory`. I have a non-rooted phone with Gingerbread 2.3.5 :). The device is a `HTC Desire S S510e`. I don't currently know how to find out the ROM - I guess I am using a stock ROM.

Comment: Fascinating. So if I had to guess, HTC probably has a watered down version of ls in their stock firmware. If you want one with colored output and the like, you'll need to install Busybox. I believe you need root for it, but you might be able to get on without root...

Comment: I guess that's a proper guess. Will try the busybox suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to type `shell` after open the `adb shell`. I'm using LMDE Mate Desktop. Using the mate-terminal.